# Insert two values into one column including a multiplication C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-insert

Hi all I am Having some problem with a program would appreciate some help.

1. Firstly I am trying to take `Donation_euro.Text` and times it by
   0.83 to get the conversion rate, I think I have done this correct but it dose not seem to be working.
   (reason for the conversion is that I can have only one currency in my database).
2. Secondly I am trying to insert `donation_total` and `donation.Text`
   into the same column, this will give my user the choice of paying in
   Euro's or Pound's. but it seems I can not do this the way I have
   tried, is there a way to fix this to get it to work?

   ```
               Double donation_euro = Convert.ToDouble(Donation_euro.Text);
               Double convertion_rate = 0.83;
               Double donation_total = donation_euro * convertion_rate;

               da.InsertCommand = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO Customer(Donation,donation_total)VALUES (@Donation)", cs);
               {

                   da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Donation", donation.Text + donation_total);
               }
   ```

**note:**
    Donation_euro.Text and `donation.Text are both text boxes and I have my table column set to double`

Comment: Replace `donation.Text + donation_total` with `donation_total`, by assuming that the DB is expecting a double value. You cannot "add" a string with a double without any cast and this is precisely what your code is doing.

Comment: Your also trying to insert into two columns `Customer(Donation,donation_total)` but you are only providing one value

Comment: OK I will try both methods thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to fill to fields using the `INSERT`, but you're only providing one value in the `VALUES` section of the statement. This gives an error in the call, as it is not valid SQL.

Change it as follows:

```
da.InsertCommand = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO Customer(Donation,donation_total) VALUES (@Donation, @Total)", cs);
{
    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Donation", donation.Text);
    da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddwithValue("@Total", donation_total);
}
```

---

Oh: And +1 for using parameterized queries!

Comment: What do you mean, *it is not working* - do you get an error? Don't you get an error, but no values are inserted?

Comment: its throwing up a error with the the eqation part, `Double donation_euro = Convert.ToDouble(Donation_euro.Text);`  says string is formatted wrong.

Comment: Well, that has nothing to do with inserting into the database. Of course you need to enter some value in the text box that can be converted to double...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Donation", donation_total);
```

instead of:

```
da.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Donation", donation.Text + donation_total);
```

Also your insert statement expects the second parameter.(Hope you are providing that in the actual code)

```
da.InsertCommand = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO Customer(Donation,donation_total)VALUES (@Donation)", cs);
```

Comment: Thank you, is not working at the moment but will keep going and let you know if it works.